# How can I show a hidden text by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display = "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <div id="myDIV"><p>This is my DIV element.</p></div 
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the css file I included the command: #myDIV{
display: none;
} because otherwise the text would not be hidden at first. With this code the text is hidden at first and if I click on the button it shows the text. But then if I click on the button again it should be closing the text which it does not. Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison. E.g. `if (x.style.display = "none")` uses the wrong one

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations with the equal signs but none of them solved my problem. Do you have a suggestion?

If I change the if ... === to 3 equal signs it works as I would like but only if I click 2 times on the button first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this to HTML

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;"><p>This is my DIV element.</p></div>
```

and this javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       x.style.display = "none";
      }
}
```

This now will work because the display none isn't by default to div element so javascript will not see the display none style and will not execute the function. So you need to specify style display none and the function will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison. So inside of the `if`, change it to one of those two.

You also didn't properly close the `<div>` in the code you submitted.

Another thing is that you're setting the `display: none` in a CSS file. JavaScript doesn't have access to this value, it only has access to `style="..."` in the HTML markup of the element. To fix this issue, check if it's **not** hidden and swap around the sides of the `if/else` block.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display == "block") { // `=` to `==` or `===`
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <div id="myDIV">
      <p>This is my DIV element.</p>
    </div> <!-- this div wasn't closed properly -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  x.style.display = x.style.display != "block"?"block":"none"
}
```

```css
#myDIV{ display: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <div id="myDIV"><p>This is my DIV element.</p></div 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP wants the div to be hidden at the start, via CSS

Comment: Thanks, edited, didn't read that initially.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use the [`details` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), which has this behavior and doesn't require any JS. You can style it the way you want (see the same link).

This would then be:

```html
<details>
  <summary>Try it</summary>
  <div>This is my DIV element</div>
</details>
```